# GAS - query date picker not working

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, datepicker

I am creating an html form where user needs to enter leave start date and end date. However, when the scripts are loaded this does not happen. I searched for all problems related to JQuery. Is there any way or any other widget that can be used to enter the date and validate that the end date is greater than the start date. It works in jsfiddle but not in GAS.

The code is given below.

Regards,

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
body
{
    font-size:8pt;
    font-family:Verdana;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });  
    <?var logged_user = getcurruser();?>

});

</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.16/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div>

<form id="leaveapp">
<?var logged_user = getcurruser();?>

<label><?=logged_user?></label>
<br/>
Leave Start Date: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
Leave End Date: <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />

</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: call your script at last

Comment: did not work. i put my script after the others in the head, but it does not do the trick. Datepicker is still a text box and when i click on it a calendar does not pop up

Comment: Use iframe mode for html

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using for jQuery is not valid: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.16/jquery.min.js`, returns a `404` error.

If you change it to a valid URL like:
`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`, everything works.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oewh0k4a/